# Refactor waterfall functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to stop waterfall functions if one found a result but i don't know how i can achieve this properly...

```
function one(data) {
   if(isSomething(data)) throw { update: true }
   else return
}
 
function two(data) {
   if(isOtherthing(data)) throw { delete: true }
   else return
}
      
function three(data) {
   if(isOtherthing(data)) throw { notify: true }
   else return
}
 
( ... some functions )
 
function main() {
   try {
      one(data)
      two(otherData)
      three(otherData2)
      ...
   }
   catch(err) {
      if(err.update) update()
      if(err.delete) delete()
      if(err.notify) notify()
   }
}
```

Do you have some ideas ? maybe with async js lib but i need to pass on callback err...

Comment: What is your question exactly? It seems like you've found *a* solution. Are you looking for a better one or..?

Comment: *Ewwwwwwwwww!* You're using exception handling as flow control!

Comment: What are the constraints? No callback function? Lesser line?

Comment: Yes im looking for a better solution ... 
I don't have constraints, juste need to have best practice to achieve this ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would point out that you may return functions in JS.

The best practice in this case would be to choose the right pattern to adopt.

For this is use case I think the [Middleware](https://medium.com/ingeniouslysimple/building-extensible-pipelines-with-middleware-4f64428cab39) or the [Chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

A quick example in sync style with an exit strategy:

```js
function updateFunc () { console.log('update') }
function deleteFunc () { console.log('delete') }
function notifyFunc () { console.log('notify') }

function one (data) {
  return isOtherthing(data) ? updateFunc : false
}

function two (data) {
  return isOtherthing(data) ? deleteFunc : false
}

function three (data) {
  return isOtherthing(data) ? notifyFunc : false
}

function main () {
  const pipes = [one, two, three]
  for (const check of pipes) {
    const returnedFunction = check({ foo: 'bar' })
    if (returnedFunction) {
      returnedFunction() // execute it
      break // stop the flow
    }
  }
}

function isOtherthing (params) {
  return true
}

main()
```

Notice that there are modules that implement those patterns.

Comment: thank for the answer i write a similar function

`async function waterfallUntilResult(array, arg) {
  for (const fn of array) {
    const result = await fn(arg)
    if (result) return result
  }
}`
i don't found on async lib this solution